# Flask SQLAlchemy Foreign Key Querying

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am quite new to Python and programming in general. I could use some help with logic.

I have 3 tables, users, posts, comments. Table comments has a column "user_id" which has a Foreign_Key to the users column "id". Also as a post_id with FK to post_id.

comments.user_id = users.id  &&  comments_post_id = posts.id

To query a specific post I am using:

```
post = Posts.query.filter_by(id=post_id).first_or_404()
```

To query the comments I am using:

```
comments = Comments.query.filter_by(post_id=post_id).order_by(Comments.time.desc()).all()
```

I would like to get the username from the users table where the comments.user_id.... This is where my logic gets scrambled.

Using the FK can I directly reference Users.username? Or does the FK just map a relationship so I can run the query. Where comments.user_id = Users.id .... get username and everything. I feel I am doing this quite inefficiently.

I'd like to replace comment.user_id with "Users.username where comment.user_id = user_id"

```
{% if comments %}
  {% for comment in comments %}
    {{ comment.user_id }}
    {{ comment.time }}
    {{ comment.comment }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I think what I need to do I make a new column in comments, comments.user_username & give it an FK of users.username. I keep getting a 150 error and the columns are identical. Same collation, datatype and length.

Comment: You'd usually [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) the user table to your comment in order to fetch that data as well. SQLAlchemy [relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html) provide the ORM side, and can be made to eagerly load the data using joins. If you for example were to have a relationship configured between *Users* and *Comments*, you could use [`joinedload(Comments.user)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload) etc.

Comment: Excellent, you've been a major help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can define a attribute which type is `relationship` of SQLAlchemy as follows:

```
class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=1)
    content = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=0)
    create_user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    create_user = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=create_user_id)
    post_id = dn.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("post.id"))
```

You can write `comment.create_user.username` in the template file.